# Randomly generate odd numbers in the range

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to generate odd numbers randomly. I tried this, but it generates even numbers also:

```
int coun=random.nextInt();
for(int i=1; i<100; i++){
    if(i%2==1){
      coun=random.nextInt(i);
    }
}
```

How can I generate odd numbers randomly?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594974/generating-an-odd-random-number-between-a-given-range

Comment: `random.nextInt(i)` returns a random value between 0 and `i`, so ensuring that `i` is odd won't ensure an odd value is returned

Comment: you cant guarantee that random.nextInt () will return a an odd or even number,its random, how ever you can process the output of random.nextInt () and ensure that the overall result is odd.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add 1 to even numbers

```
    int x=(int) (Math.random()*100);
    x+=(x%2==0?1:0);
```

or multiply the number by 2 and add one

```
    int x=(int) (Math.random()*100);
    x=x*2+1;
```

a lot of possible solutions.

Comment: In the second solution, if you want the range from 1 to 9 then the output might be also 15 greater than 9!

Comment: Your question didn't specify any constraint, these are just examples, anyway

Answer (score 4):

All numbers of the form `2*n + 1` are odd. So one way to generate a random odd number would be, to generate a random integer, multiply it by 2, and add 1 to it:

```
int n = random.nextInt();
int r = 2 * n + 1; // Where r is the odd random number
```

For each random number `n`, there is a unique odd random number `r` generated (in other words, it is a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)) - thus ensuring unbiasedness (or at least, as much unbiasedness as the function `random.nextInt()`).

Comment: But what about if you want odd nums from 1 to 10? then when you do this operation 2 * n + 1 it will give more than 10

Comment: Then make sure that you generate an `n` such that `2 * n + 1 < 10`. Or, `n < (9/2) = 4`. I think [Peter has a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32554155/1492578) for you.

Comment: @user1364513 Then ask for random numbers from 1 to 4

Answer (score 4):

There is 50 odd numbers between 0 and 100. To select one of them you can do

```
int n = random.nextInt(50);
```

to get the n-th odd number you can

```
int odd = n * 2 + 1;
```

Putting it all together

```
int odd = random.nextInt(max / 2) * 2 + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to test wheter the random integer value is odd or not. If it is not, you can add or subtract one with half probability.

```
Random random = new Random();
int i = random.nextInt();
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    i += random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: nextInt() is already any possible int value.  There is no bias if you just add 1 each time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey because of integer overflow right? Otherwise, `Integer.MIN_VALUE+1` can never be generated.

Comment: Yes, because of overflow and underflow it doesn't matter if you add one or subtract one, you will get the same distribution.